# How to Copy Row Height and Column Width From one Excel File to Another

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to copy one excel worksheet from one excel workbook to another excel worksheet in a different excel workbook.

Currently I can copy the values and formatting of all of the cells. The only thing that doesn't work is that the column and row height don't match.

Also, if there are "groupings" (which I'm not sure are technically hidden cells in excel) I need to be able to group those.

Does anyone have a clue how to do this?

As for the row height part at least, I've been trying to figure out how to use the height method. Intially I'm just trying to print out the height dimensions to see if I can iterate over them, but no luck so far.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Documents/test/DISCIPLINEDEQUITYATTR_EAFE_AlphaAttribution_3YRS_20180928_CLPSE.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

for i in ws.row_dimensions[2].height:
    print(i)
```

But I just get the error TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

See code below

```
import openpyxl as xl
from copy import copy


path1 = 'Documents/test/DISCIPLINEDEQUITYATTR_EAFE_AlphaAttribution_3YRS_20180928_CLPSE.xlsx'
path2 = 'Documents/test/DISCIPLINEDEQUITYATTR_EAFE_AlphaAttribution_3YRS_20180928_CLPSE_COPY.xlsx'

wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path1)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path2)
ws2 = wb2.create_sheet(ws1.title)

for row in ws1:
    for cell in row:
        new_cell = ws2.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.col_idx, value=cell.value)
        if cell.has_style:
            new_cell.font = copy(cell.font)
            new_cell.border = copy(cell.border)
            new_cell.fill = copy(cell.fill)
            new_cell.number_format = copy(cell.number_format)
            new_cell.protection = copy(cell.protection)
            new_cell.alignment = copy(cell.alignment)

wb2.save(path2)
```

Comment: AFAICT, the error message is saying whats going on…  the row has one height and it's stored in a float that you're trying to iterate through, try just printing the height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to copy the row and column dimensions. The code for this is very similar to that for copying cells.

```
for idx, rd in ws1.row_dimensions.items():
     ws2.row_dimensions[idx] = copy(rd)
```

This might need additional code if there are styles involved.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Set the row height and column width of the destination cell to match the source


ws2.column_dimensions[new_cell.column_letter].width = ws1.column_dimensions[cell.column_letter].width

ws2.row_dimensions[new_cell.row].height = ws1.row_dimensions[cell.row].height
```