# split excel sheet in python pandas without loosing source formatting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, export-to-excel

I'm trying to split an excel file in pycharm by importing pandas. My code is splitting the sheet based on key value and properly copying the text in the target. But the source file format is not being copied. I want the sheet to be splitted along with source formatting. [The sample files are in the link](https://mega.nz/folder/c7ByyK5C#SPVb1YRjoJSIZT7E1eHyaQ) and the screenshots are available at
[Master file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKmug.jpg) and
[Split file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTi4N.jpg)

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'mypath\myfile.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet2',engine='openpyxl')

target_folder = 'my target folder'

keys = df.groupby('STD')

key_value = keys.groups.keys()

for key in key_value: 
        splitdf = keys.get_group(key)
        splitdf.to_excel(str(target_folder)+str(key)+".xlsx",sheet_name=str(key),index=False)

print("Files created in " + str(target_folder) + "Folder")
```

Answer (score 0):

AFIK, this can't be done with pandas. You have to use [openpyxl](/questions/tagged/openpyxl).

Here is a proposition with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) based on your master [*file*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKmug.jpg).

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from itertools import groupby

wb = load_workbook("myfile.xlsx")
ws = wb.active # or wb["Sheet2"]

data = ws.rows
header = [(h._style, h.value) for h in next(data)]
pairs = [[(r._style, r.value) for r in rows] for rows in data]

groups = {
    std: list(g) for std, g in groupby(
        sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x[1][1]), key=lambda x: x[1][1])
}

for std, vals in groups.items():
    std_ws = wb.create_sheet(std)
        
    for idxr, rows in enumerate(*[[header] + vals], 1):
        for idxc, (s, v) in enumerate(rows, 1):
            wb[std].cell(idxr, idxc).value = v
            wb[std].cell(idxr, idxc)._style = s

    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/52736133/16120011
    from copy import copy
    for idx, rd in ws.column_dimensions.items():
        std_ws.column_dimensions[idx] = copy(rd)

del wb["Sheet2"] # could be unnecessary

wb.save("newfile.xlsx")
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issues I faced after updating the code are, that the file is creating a new workbook with different sheets but I want new workbooks instead of worksheet in same workbook. Second issue where can I update the key value. In the present code groupby function grouping second column. What if I want to change the key value to third or fourth column.